# Can I define \supercite to act as \cite?

Tags: macros

I have a document using supercite and it works fine, but I am now using a different set of packages and cite works better. So rather than me have to change them all, is there a way I can define `\supercite` to act as `\cite`?

Comment: In general `let\supercite\cite` would do a command reassignment. But you would have to make sure the argument lists are compatible (I am not familiar with supercite to know).  Of course, using your text editor to do a global search and replace is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating and expanding my comment as an answer (per Joseph Wright's request):

The general way to substitute one existing command for another existing command is with the use of `\let`.  In the current case, that would take the syntax

```
\let\supercite\cite
```

in order to make calls to `\supercite` use a copy of the code of `\cite`. It is important to note that `\let` makes a copy of the code, so that, if later in your code, you were to reassign `\cite`, the assigned `\supercite` will still contain a copy of the original `\cite` code.

One must be careful that the argument structure to both commands are compatible.  If not, you will, at a minimum, lose some functionality, or at worst, break existing code. (I am not familiar with `\supercite`, but a few questions on this site that reference the command would seem to indicate that the argument list is compatible with `\cite`.)

One other thing folks will often do is save a copy of a command before reassigning it, such as

```
\let\savesupercite\supercite
\let\supercite\cite
```

In this way, the original `\supercite` code is available in `\savesupercite` if, later in a document, you have a need to reinvoke the unaltered code, or need to re-reassign it.

Here's an MWE that shows how `\let` would reassign things in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0ex
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\def\cite{CITE}
\def\supercite{SUPERCITE}

\let\savesupercite\supercite
\let\supercite\cite

Upon reassignment, \verb|\supercite| calls upon \supercite

whereas \verb|\savesupercite| can be used to recover the original
\savesupercite{} code.

\def\cite{XXX}
Even if I reassign \verb|\cite| to \cite, the reassigned
\verb|\supercite| still contains a copy of the original \supercite{} code.
\end{document}
```

[image]

All these things being said, your question indicated that the desire to reassign `\supercite` to use `\cite` arose to save yourself typing/deleting within a particularly long document, rather than as a coding substitution that you wished to adopt for your general use.  In such cases, the use of search and replace features of your text editor should allow for a change of the invocations from `\supercite` to `\cite` without having to reassign any commands.  Doing so helps avoid confusion in a reader of your code, since it will allow the reader to immediately understand that you are, in fact, using `\cite` and not `\supercite`.